# Is it safe to add 1 TB hard drive to laptop if system manual does not recommend 1 TB?

Tags: hard-drive

My HP 8540w laptop user manual has not listed 1 TB-volume hard disks as its replacement parts. Instead, only 500, 250, and up to 640 GB are mentioned. I would like to replace the current degrading 500 GB with a brand new 1 TB, but I am not sure it will work. Is it safe to go and buy a 1 TB-volume hard disk with the same form factor as of the current one as a replacement and have it work on my system?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might not have existed or have been an option at the time - or the drive might have not been the right thickness.

Most SSDs and smaller drives are 7mm thick - if your 1tb drive is the older, thicker format it may not *physically* fit.

If its the right thickness, it should probably fit in fine.

The OS/interface should have no issues addressing or booting off of a 1tb drive

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesnt list a 1TB drive is most likely because there was no 1TB hard drive availlable for your product at the time.(Not one made by the manufacturer themselves atleast)

That being said Hard drives are all made according to industry standards and there shouldn't be any reason for a 1TB drive not to work. Just make sure you buy the right form factor.

Comment: Precisly. The only issue could be with >2TiB drives and older laptops with a BIOS  rather than EFI or with an ancient OS like XP.  There are workarounds for those though.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problem using a 1TB HDD as the storage is managed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put up to a 2TB drive in any PC (unless specified otherwise)
You can also expand your storage MORE by adding a HDD caddy,
this caddy replaces your ODD (cd drive) with a bracket for a HDD

The website you are looking at only talks about their replacement parts.

[Source](http://www.notebookcheck.nl/Testrapport-HP-Elitebook-8540w-Notebook.33604.0.html)

The site has a full review of your laptop, it says that they put a 1TB drive in the laptop with another one in a drive expansion bay, and that raid 0 or 1 was possible in the BIOS settings. They also said that the laptop has 12.5mm drives, so a smaller (way more common) drive is compatible with the slots, but beware of the few millimeters that are left in the slots when you fill them with smaller drives.

Conclusion:
YES, buying a common, but smaller drive is possible, your laptop will work with that drive, but for data safety and drive health reasons i would put something thick, soft and antistatic in your laptop WITH the drive to make it fit better.

Comment: +1, I don't understand the Dutch source. Can you please tell me what the article is all about? Sure it is about 8540w but not sure what precisely it discusses. And why should be problems for storage beyond 2 TB?

Comment: It is a full review of your laptop, it says that they put a 1TB drive in the laptop with another one in a drive expansion bay, and that raid 0 or 1 was possible.
They also said that you had 12.5mm drives, so a smaller (way more common) drive is compatible with the slots, but beware of the few millimeter that are left in the slots when you fill them with smaller drives.